# My script incorrectly adds 1 extra int to game propert, why?

Tags: python, game-engine

been spending this whole day trying to figure out why
my script adds 1 extra (wrongfully) int to the property 'score'.
All code works, excepts that the IF statement adds one extra int, messing up the score since only one int should be added.
[image]
I'm a newbie to scripting so an answer would be beautiful.
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about code review and not about Blender

Comment: @VRM I don't agree, this is about using the BGE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keyboard sensors will keep triggering while the key is pressed, possibly triggering your script twice or more for a single key press. To solve this, enable the "Tap" button so that it only triggers once for a press.

I can also recommend reading up on [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It gives you guidance on naming conventions; following it makes it easier to collaborate with others, and also makes it easier for us to understand your code and help you with issues.

Comment: Thanks, but please if you have an advice, how can i Fix it? - I want to save the text input from user only as one string and not have a double signal as currently.
or are there any relevant tutorial somewhere you recommend?

Comment: I've updated my answer for this.

Comment: The tap switch will not help. The sensor will still trigger the controller at two frames (when pressing and the frame after). As any other controller your python controller should check the status of the connected sensors. See https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?221409-The-BGE-GameLoop and https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?249757-Prof.-Monster-s-BGE-Guide-to-Python-Coding